# I have a ListView with ViewFlippers as rows. I need a list of slideshow of images on each row. Read details

Tags: android, listview, adapter, swipe, viewflipper

I am a newbie to android programming.

I somehow managed to load the images and set them to auto flipping. What I need is two things.

1. Each image inside each ViewFLipper is a link to another activity. So I need to set an onClick listener for the ViewFlipper that opens the corresponding activity for each image. I can't seem to get that to work. Code attached below.
2. I also need for the user to be manually able to scroll (swipe right and left) through each ViewFlipper and see any image she likes (in addition to the auto flipping). I can't understand how to get that done.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer[]> {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, Integer[][] resource) {
        super(context,R.layout.custom_row_main ,resource);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row_main, parent, false);

        View view1 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, parent, false);

        Integer[] resIds = getItem(position);

        final ViewFlipper viewFlipper1 = (ViewFlipper) view.findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);

        for(int i=0;i<resIds.length;i++)
        {
            ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(getContext());
            imageButton.setBackgroundResource(resIds[i]);
            viewFlipper1.addView(imageButton);
        }

        viewFlipper1.setFlipInterval(5000);

        viewFlipper1.startFlipping();

        viewFlipper1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Intent to open the required activity
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

Using viewflippers for this was like reinventing the wheel. Just used viewpagers inside a listview. Worked like a charm.

Still can't get the auto scrolling to work, though.

Will update when I do.